# How to create Google map fixed marker with postal address

Tags: javascript, google-maps, geocoding

I use this script to show a Google fixed map `It's marker in the center always`

```
 <script>
    function initialize() {
        var mapOptions = {
            zoom: 5,
            center: new google.maps.LatLng(52.5498783, 13.425209099999961),
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        };
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'),
            mapOptions);

        $('<div/>').addClass('centerMarker').appendTo(map.getDiv())
            //do something onclick
            .click(function() {
                var that = $(this);
                if (!that.data('win')) {
                    that.data('win', new google.maps.InfoWindow({
                        content: '<div>' + '<span>Location: ' + map.getCenter().lat() + '</span>' + '</div>',
                        maxWidth: 350,
                    }));
                    that.data('win').bindTo('position', map, 'center');
                }
                that.data('win').open(map);
            });

        google.maps.event.addListener(map,'center_changed', function() {
            $('.MapLat').val(map.getCenter().lat());
            $('.MapLng').val(map.getCenter().lng());
        });
    }
    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
 </script>
```

and it works just fine. The issue is how to add postal address that shows in the marker content?